# Google actions - Webhook

Tags: action, dialogflow-es, fulfillment

I have some issues with Webhook and Web integration.

I have created intents and the response is from Webhook APIcall. when I try to test the intent with web integration, my response is shown as "[empty response]"

What is wrong with this?

[image: empty response from Webhook]

Answer (score 0):

This means your webhook isn't sending back a response or isn't sending a response back fast enough and Dialogflow is using the built-in responses.

Check your webhook logs to see how quickly it is replying and what it is sending back to Dialogflow.

Answer (score 0):

You might have forgot to enable webhook for Intent at the bottom of the Intent config page.

[image]

You can also test your intent from Testing Panel at Right Hand Side.

1. Type user query related to your Intent in textbox in Testing Panel.
2. Click on "Show Json" at the bottom of Testing Panel.
3. Check the response from your web hook in JSON window.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reply Prisoner. we have seen the log as you said. The Dialogflow is returning the output as expected Json Format below,

```
{
  "messages":[
  {
     "speech":"Hi, I am your bot",
     "type":0
  },
  {
     "platform":"google",
     "type":"simple_response",
     "displayText":"Hi, I am your test bot",
     "textToSpeech":"Hi, I am your test bot"
  },
  {
     "platform":"google",
     "type":"suggestion_chips",
     "suggestions":[
        {
           "title":"Read more"
        }
     ]
  }
]
}
```

The above output is working on Google Home / Assistant Device. but we could not able to integrate with web demo.